# I got this code to inset an element at the end of the list.Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

***Hey guys i code this code for inserting an element at the end of the list***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
   struct node *link;
};
struct node*head;
void insert(int x){
    struct node*temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->data=x;
   temp->link=NULL;
   struct node*temp1=head;
   while(temp1->link!=NULL)
       temp1=temp1->link;
   temp1->link=temp;
};
void display(){
    struct node*temp=head;
    printf("LIst is:");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
};
int main()
{ head=NULL;
    int n,i,x;
    printf("Enter the number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the elements:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(x);
        display();
    }

}
```

Every time i compile it.It shows

```
Segmentation fault core dumped
```

*please help*
**i don't know what wrong**
***am i accessing memory that “does not belong to me.***

Comment: "Every time i compile ..." -> "Every time i execute ..."

Comment: That code doesn't even compile...

Comment: your `head` pointer is NULL the first time. NULL->next is segmentation fault.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: regarding: `struct node*temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  The cast: `(node*)` is not valid, there is nothing named `node`!  Perhaps you meant: `(struct node*)`.   However, in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,   Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).   Also, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `void insert(int x){
    struct node*temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->data=x;
   temp->link=NULL;
   struct node*temp1=head;
   while(temp1->link!=NULL)
       temp1=temp1->link;
   temp1->link=temp;
};`  Do NOT place a semicolon after the closing brace of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign `head` to `temp1`

```
struct node*temp1=head;
```

And at this moment `head` is `NULL`

then you dereference `temp1` (`NULL`)

```
while(temp1->link!=NULL)
```

That's why you get a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

`head` is `NULL` to start with. So when you do:

```
struct node*temp1=head;
while(temp1->link!=NULL)
        ^^^^^
```

you dereference `NULL` and the program crashes.

You need an extra `if` statement like to handle the case where `head` is `NULL`.

```
...
temp->link=NULL;
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = temp;
    return;
}
struct node*temp1=head;
...
```

BTW: In general it's a bad idea to have a global variable `head`.

To avoid a global variable you can do two things - either return the `head` pointer on every call to `insert` or pass the addsress of the `head` to the function. I prefer the last. It looks like:

```
void insert(struct node** pHead, int x){
   struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->data=x;
   temp->link=NULL;
   if (*pHead == NULL)
   {
       *pHead = temp;  // Update head
       return;
   }
   struct node* temp1 = *pHead;
   while(temp1->link!=NULL)
       temp1=temp1->link;
   temp1->link=temp;
};
```

and call it like:

```
int main()
{ 
    struct node* head=NULL;  // Use a local variable
    int n,i,x;
    printf("Enter the number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the elements:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(&head, x);  // Pass the address of head
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.And sorry about the global variable i am new at this.... this was really helpful

Comment: @zyphr_Flaw No need for "sorry". It was just an advice for you - try to avoid global variables. Instead pass the `head` (or rather `&head`) into the function. Have fun learning C